# Why the scaled square does not have it's center in (1, 1) coordinates?

Tags: opengl, matrix, transformation

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>



void drawTriangle()
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex2d(0.5, 0.5);

    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex2d(-0.5, 0.5);

    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex2d(-0.5, -0.5);

    glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
    glVertex2d(0.5, -0.5);

    glEnd();
}

void displayFunction()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    drawTriangle();

    glScaled(0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
  //  glRotated(30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glTranslated(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    drawTriangle();

    glFlush();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Clipping with a plane");
    glutDisplayFunc(displayFunction);

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I expected to see the small square center to be in the top-right corner of the window in (1, 1) coordinates. Why it is not there?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

You should invert the order of transformations - first translation then scaling.

Longer one:

All transformations in OpenGL are applied as matrix multiplication. For instance in Your case when You do scaling first current model-view matrix is multiplied by a **scaling matrix**, *then* the outcome is multiplied by **translation matrix**. The order should be inverse because the scaling actually changes whole coordinates system. This means that any transformation done after scaling by 0.5, say moving the point by 1.0 will actually move it by 0.5. In case of doing translation first it will go 1.0 in some direction and then scale by 0.5. As You can see in such a case order of execution is important - outcome of matrix multiplication depends on the order of the matrices used.

Matrix stack in OpenGL is used in case of some kind of hierachical rendering like solar system for instance. To use it one should call two routines: `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix`. `glPushMatrix` saves current state of the used matrix (set up by `glMatrixMode`) to its relevent stack, while `glPopMatrix` loads it from the stack overriding any previous changes done to the current matrix.

It is also essential to call `glLoadIndentity` before doing any transformation on a chosen matrix, to prevent them to pile up over time. It basically overrides current selected matrix with an identity one, canceling any applied transformations beforehand.

Comment: That is true it works. But to explain let's understand how the scale and translation work. Let's discuss only `X` axis. When you scale you multiply `x` coordinate of a vertex by `Sx` - in our case `0.5`. Then when you translate, you add `x` coordinate `Tx` - in our case `1.0`. So what is the problem? My code should work as `0.0 * 0.5 + 1.0 = 1.0` , right?

Comment: I guess my confusion comes because `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);` sets the matrix stack. As it is a **stack** my operations will be applied in inverse order. When I write first scale then translate, then it first takes out of the stack translate and then scale, therefore I see unexpected result. Is this true?

Comment: if I want to make it 2 times smaller and move by 1 unit right what is the right way Scale then Translate, or vice versa? I think I should Scale then Translate. And in order to Scale then Translate I should write `glTranslated(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);  glScaled(0.5, 0.5, 1.0);` (inverse order) do you agree?

Comment: Translate then Scale:
`glTranslated(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); glScaled(0.5, 0.5, 1.0); drawTriangle();`
Above snippet should work for moving the polygon You want to draw by 1 unit right and scale it down by 2.